# What 80s BBC kids’ TV show had children fitting together machinery they found in the countryside?

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember a series that I liked in the 80's. It was about a group of children that may have lived on a farm.  They found pieces of machinery in the local countryside which they found fitted together.  It definitely had a sci-fi type feel to it and was a live action show.

I think the series was probably on after Newsround for 20-30mins. It may have been an import.

I never saw all the episodes, sorry for being vague.  Also I never saw an ending if there was one.

**EDIT**

There was maybe a swamp where they found a ring of the device
Also there was a girl and boy and possibly another character other than family members (mum, dad etc)

Comment: Live action or animated?

Comment: Also, this might provide some inspiration: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_BBC_children's_television_programmes

Comment: It is a live action program.

Comment: I really have a feeling it was an import I remember an accent so prob not made by the bbc i'll have a look though

Comment: “on after Newsround for 20-30mins” — ah, the summer replacements for Grange Hill/Byker Grove.

Comment: Do you remember something about the plot? Alien visitors? Military? Are we talking about fiction or is this edutainment teaching kids about mechanics?

Comment: @Dreamwalker that list does seem to have some imports such as Round the Twist on it.

Comment: This is defiantly fictional.  I have scanned the list but nothing rang a bell

Comment: As mentioned it was in the county side I am thinking there was a swamp as well where they found a part was a metal type ring may have had a hole in the middle.

Comment: @Dreamwalker: Swamp. Could be Children of the Dog Star? a New Zealand production from 1984. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children_of_the_Dog_Star It is listed as airing in Britain in august 1985: http://www.mjsimpson.co.uk/timeline/1980s.html

Comment: Yes that's it! Children of the dog star.  Wasn't quite a ring though in the swamp :S bad memory there lol. See if I can find it on dvd now :)

Comment: Found it on amazon sweet :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could be "[Children of the Dog Star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children_of_the_Dog_Star)"(NZ 1984) which [aired in Britain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children_of_the_Dog_Star) in August '85. The show features children in a rural setting, it's SciFi and includes something in a swamp with circular shape, which is recovered by the children. Below is the recovery from the swamp and assorted mystery devices from the show:

[image]
[image]

Source: http://www.frequency.com/video/children-of-dog-star-1984/101862698/-/5-6263323

---

Edit: First guess was that it could have been a re-run of "Here Come the Double Deckers" from 1970-71. It takes place in a junk yard in London where a group of children live in an abandoned double-decker bus. It features a fair bit of tinkering and a robot in at least one episode.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not it

Comment: @Dreamwalker: Could it be "Read all about it!" which has a somewhat more rural setting and more clearly scifi? http://www.rickstv.com/tvo/read.html