# What 80s kids show had alien flying discs giving advice to children in a barn?

Tags: story-identification

This really is a Hail Mary throw, but it’s been bugging me for years.

I watched a children’s show in the 1980s which revolved around an alien presence giving advice and other interaction to a small group of children. The alien was represented by several flying discs which took up positions in a barn when called by the children - one of the signature shots was the discs traveling at high speed through a tunnel to get to the barn.

I remember it was in English, and I saw it in the UK.

I can confirm that after watching it, Children of the Dog Star is not the show I am after.

Comment: “I have no further details I’m afraid.” — sure you do. What language was it in, and what country did you watch it in?

Comment: English and UK.

Comment: It sounds a little like the 1987 movie [*Batteries Not Included*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092494/) .

Comment: @JoeL. Nope, not that movie - very distinctly completely different to that.

Comment: What age were the children? Why did they need advice from an alien?

Comment: [Children of the Dog Star](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0271902/) perhaps? It's the right time period, though it's from New Zealand rather than the UK.

Comment: @andrewsi it aired in the UK also. There are some pictures on a question I asked trying to identify it. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51769/what-80s-bbc-kids-tv-show-had-children-fitting-together-machinery-they-found-in

Comment: @Dreamwalker that definitely looks promising.  Will have to grab a copy of the series to see if it ties in with my memory.  Cheers!

Comment: @andrewsi tried to copy you in to the above, but SE wouldn't let me :)

Comment: @moo At least it's easier to buy now I had to get it imported from new zeland :)

Comment: I remember it. I'm looking for it too! I'm sure the head of the probe thing was on the top of the barn. I remember it giving ecological advice. Here's to finding it!

Comment: You could try looking through all the UK "telefantasy" series from the 1980s on [this page](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/john.seymour1/telefantasylist/whatistelefantasy.html) to see if anything rings a bell.

Comment: I checked this [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:1980s_British_children%27s_television_series) and nothing jumps out. Was it possibly a 60s/70s show being re-run, or an imported tv series?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage either of those two possibilities is high.  The image of three discs, slightly larger than frisbee sized, sitting on poles with the centre one slightly higher than the others, is very very clear in my head - as is the discs travelling down a tunnel to get to the poles when they are summoned.  Im sure that the tunnel is investigated in one episode, but otherwise its something the human kids involved dont think about or probably even see.

Answer (score 3):

Are these the flying discs?

[image: Chocky]

If so, it is from [Chocky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chocky_(TV_series)) which was shown in 1984 in the UK.

[Here's a good summary with more screenshots / videos](https://cultfaction.com/tag/chocky/).

Comment: Nope, afraid not.  The disks I am thinking of were very specifically something like miniature UFOs, probably no more than a meter across.  Chocky was the answer to another of my questions however ;)

Comment: @Moo - ah, well :) I will delete, thanks.

Comment: No no no, thank *you* :)

Answer (score -1):

Wild guess as there are no disks involved in the following but perhaps it's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sky_(TV_serial) They are not in a barn per se but in sort of a mine and earth ecological system is rejecting the alien.

Comment: If it doesnt have flying disks, it ain't what I'm after I'm afraid :(

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is [Benji, Zax & the Alien Prince](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benji,_Zax_%26_the_Alien_Prince)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you give us some more details of the show so we can see how it matches the question?

Comment: No, that doesn't sound like it at all, sorry.