# Looking for tv series title about space ship hidden on earth

Tags: tv, spaceship, story-identification

I've seen this show as a kid, and sadly - was not able to find any info using Google. Back at the time it was aired in Poland, its title was translated as "Andromeda" (or "Andromeda" was part of the title), but as with any early-90s title translations, it had nothing to do with its English counterpart. And no, it was not the Andromeda with Kevin Sorbo, so after no luck, without further ado, let's piece what I remember:

- the action took place on Earth;
- there was a hidden spaceship, somewhere in the woods, inside rocks/hill;
- I believe the main character (probably a girl, if my memory doesn't mislead me) found the way to access it;
- the main protagonist was hunted by other creatures (possibly they were from the Andromeda);
- I remember something about piecing a triangular artifact together, from separate parts, and I somehow believe it was supposed to activate the ship (but I may be wrong about it);
- one of the scenes I remember involved this completed, triangular artifact, that the protagonist used to defend himself/herself against creatures that hunted him/her, and when he/she put it in one of the creatures, it melted down (or something in that matter happened to it).

I don't recall any other details, unfortunately, I saw this way, way back, something like probably 20 years ago. Does this look familiar to any of you? I would love to see it again, so any of your help is more than appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like "Under the Mountain" from 1981

Comment: I think it may be children of the dog star see here http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/51779/17122.  not all things match my memory of the show though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are looking for [The Boy from Andromeda](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101503/) from 1991.

It features a girl who finds a strange metal piece on a volcano and discovers that two local children (a girl and a boy) each found another one as well. They need to piece it together to reactivate the ship (which has fallen on the mountain) and the "fire key" that they piece together is the key to the ship.

The ship brought with it a child from Andromeda who is shipwrecked on earth and is sent home.

Comment: looks a better match funny thing is someone says it's a rehash of children of the dog star from the same writer.

Comment: @Dreamwalker yeah, I thought about children from the dog star as well, but it didn't ring with me. "under the Mountain" was the other one and when I was looking for it I noticed that it couldn't be it but I stumbled across The Boy from Andromeda and then my memories came back :)

Comment: That is it! Boy from Andromeda! Thank you so, so much! Time to re-live my youth (after I get back from work... sigh) :)

Comment: *"It features a girl who finds a strange metal piece on a vulcan"* Do you mean volcano? Or is there some *Star Trek* cross-over here? "Excuse me, sir, but you seem to have a strange piece of metal on you, let me get that... Oh, and nice body mod with the ears!"

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - by "vulcan" they must have meant an [Avro Vulcan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avro_Vulcan), surely one of the prettiest aircraft ever to grace the skies. ("Although", he said, his fake mustache and eyebrows waggling mischievously, "what that girl was doing on a Vulcan I'll never know..!" :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah... That was my German slipping through. I fixed it. Thank you.